Does God have a soul according to Presbyterians?
The question is: According to Presbyterians, does God have a soul?
Understandably, the answer will have to incorporate the Presbyterian definition of 'soul' and, if yes, whether it differs from the 'human soul'.
I apologize for the phrasing of the 'title'. The original was being wrongly resisted as a duplicate by the bot.
Related: Do Baptists say God has a soul?, What is the Methodist position on God's soul?, According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?, A question for Roman Catholicism about the soul of God?, What does Lutheranism say about God's soul?, Do Anglicans think God has a soul?, Do Pentecostals teach that God has a soul?

First, I would be clear as to what I take "God" to mean, in the context of this question. There is much Presbyterian literature on the Son of God, Jesus Christ, regarding a soul. There is no ambiguity regarding Jesus, for this recurring sentence is quite clear:
"Our Lord had a truly human body and a rational soul." Too many references to list here.
However, I answer on the understanding that "God" here means the totality of God (if I may put it that way, for clarity.) This is not singling out any of the three Persons, but dealing with the one true God, who Jesus said "is Spirit" (John 4:24). Further, we are told that, "No man hath seen God at any time; the only begotten Son, which is in the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him." (John 1:18)
Second, the meaning of the word ‘soul’ in Presbyterian theology: It speaks of ‘soul’ in the context of humanity, never of God. The point is made that man IS a soul, not that man HAS a soul. It speaks of ‘soul’ in the context of created humanity, never of God, who did all the creating. Here is an example:

“The great ontological distinction in the Bible is between God and
everything else, not between spirit (or mind) and body (or matter).
Materialists are wrong… when they reduce human nature to
physical-chemical components and processes. Plato, not the Scriptures,
has taught us to think of the soul as a supernatural – even divine –
part of us that has existed eternally. The soul is not an emanation of
divinity entombed in a physical body; it is a natural but nonphysical
aspect of our creatureliness. The soul is not divine, nor is the body
demonic or evil; full humanity is a psychosomatic (body-soul) unity.
We do not have a body (as if the soul were our real selves); we are
created as a psychosomatic (soul-body) whole. As persons. Our bodies
(including our brains) and souls are not separate compartments, but
interactive aspects of our personal existence and activity.” Pilgrim
Theology, Michael Horton, p 120, Zondervan, 2011

Given these statements in that Presbyterian book – “The soul is not an emanation of divinity entombed in a physical body; it is a natural but nonphysical aspect of our creatureliness. The soul is not divine”, it can be seen why God is never spoken of as being a soul, let alone having a soul.
It also becomes clear why there is such confusion, with most ideas about the human soul being based on Plato and not the scriptures. But to get the Presbyterian grasp of what the human soul is, leads to the view that God can never be said to be a soul, or to have a soul. This other book neatly shows the category error of trying to discover if God is a soul, or has a soul, by examining what the soul is, in man:

“The question, What is God?... may mean What is He essentially?
(quid)… The closest Scripture comes to answering the question is in
the statement “God is a spirit”, (John 4:24). It is important to note
the limitation of this assertion, however. God is unique. He is sui
generis. There is only one God and he may not be categorised. He is
not one of a class. There is no other form of being with which the
being of God is continuous or in terms of which His nature can be
understood. The only adequate answer to the question, ‘What is God
essentially?’ is the tautology, God is godhead. The essence of God is
deity.” Behold Your God, Donald Macleod, p. 28, cfp, 1990

God alone is independent existence. Or, as the Westminster Confession puts it: “God hath all life, glory, goodness, blessedness, in and of himself; and is alone in and unto himself all-sufficient, not standing in need of any creatures which he hath made, not deriving any glory from them, but only manifesting his own glory, in, by, unto, and upon them…” The Westminster Confession of Faith for Study Classes, G.I. Williamson, p. 23, II Of God, point 2.
That is why this answer says that the Bible only speaks of ‘soul’ in context of created creatures, and never with regard to God the Creator.

"Too many references to list here." ??? — Google Search found only one match for me for that quoted quotation, and it times out if I try to look at it: "ia801507.us.archive.org took too long to respond.".

@RayButterworth  That exact quote may only be found once, in the 1977 reprint book I took it from - In Understanding Be Men, p.98 (speaking of Jesus as man). If your ref. is different, then you now have 2. Very similar but slightly different wording is found littered through Presbyterian literature dealing with the soul of Christ as man. It continues to amaze me that google searches are considered to be the ultimate authority in gleaning such quotation information. Just go to any index, under Soul, in any Presbyterian book where the theology of the person of Christ is detailed.

What about passages like Leviticus 26:11 and a few others?  How are these dealt with?.

@MikeBorden  The verses following give the meaning. Lev 26:30 "my soul will abhor you" is Hebrew idiom for God's pure disgust of idol worship. When God speaks of “my soul” it means his deepest depths are stirred; not that God has a soul. We all know there are times when anthropomorphic meaning is valid. When the Bible speaks of God as having hair like wool, and a beard etc that is not to be taken literally. So when God is said to refer to "my soul" when speaking to his people. They can relate that to God revealing to them something of the depths of his being, for he is uncreated Spirit.
